# Не работает JQuery внутри setInterval() и setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не работает вот такой код (для слайд баннера):

```
function slideBannerAnimation(numbersOfSlides){
    var currentSlide = 0;
    var clicked = false;
    $("#slideBanner").css({overflow:"hidden", height:"432px"});
    $(".control").css("display", "block")
    .click(function(){
        currentSlide = ($(this).attr("id") == "toPrevious")?currentSlide-1:currentSlide+1;
        clicked = true;
        if(currentSlide < 0)
            currentSlide = numbersOfSlides;
        if(currentSlide > numbersOfSlides)
            currentSlide = 0;
        $("#slideContainer").animate({
            "margin-left":$(document).width()*(-currentSlide)
        }, 800);

    });
    if(!clicked){//С этого момента не работает. Всё остальное, как по часам
        setInterval(function(){
            $("#slideContainer").animate({
                "margin-left":$(document).width()*(-currentSlide)
            });
        }, 3000);
    }
}
```

Подскажите, как заставить анимацию срабатывать с интервалом, если пользователь не кликнул на кнопки контроля.

Comment: С чего вы взяли что не работает? У вас currentSlide всегда ноль при каждом срабатывании setInterval

Comment: Не заметил, спасибо за наводку.

Answer (score 0):

```
function slideBannerAnimation(numbersOfSlides){
    var currentSlide = 0;
    var timerID; // переменная для хранения ID таймера

    // функция прокрутки слайда
    slide = function (back) {
        currentSlide = back ? currentSlide - 1 : currentSlide + 1;
        if (currentSlide < 0)
            currentSlide = numbersOfSlides;
        if (currentSlide > numbersOfSlides)
            currentSlide = 0;
        $("#slideContainer").animate({
            "margin-left": $(document).width() * (-currentSlide)
        }, 800);
    }

    $("#slideBanner").css({overflow: "hidden", height: "432px"});
    $(".control").css("display", "block")
    .click(function(){
        slide($(this).attr("id") == "toPrevious");
        clearInterval(timerID); // остановить таймер
    });

    // запуск таймера
    timerID = setInterval(function(){
        slide(); // если надо в обратную сторону, то slide(true)
    }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Понял идею вашего кода, очень изящно.